# Waking in a state of janaba when fasting

Tags: fiqh, sawm, ghusl

Will a fasting be valid if somebody slept in a state of janabah and woke up at already the time of the Fajr (Subuh) prayer without having the time to do suhoor (pre-dawn meal) and without having the time to take a bath before dawn?

Or a second case, if somebody slept in a state of janaba, then woke up having only 15 minutes before the adhan for the Fajr (Subuh) prayer, thus having only enough time to do only suhoor (pre-dawn meal) and didn't have time to take a bath, but then took a bath after the adhan of the Fajr (Subuh) Prayer before doing the prayer,  would his fasting that day be valid?

Because we sometimes can't control how much we sleep esp after a state of janaba, often oversleeping in that case can happen.

Salam

Comment: @Medi1Saif Sorry for asking this but based on the answers that were over there, then if I were to "-jac-l-te" 1 minute or 10 minutes before the dawn azhan, my fast would still be valid?

Comment: If the adhan is on time yes! If it was held later or it is only based on calculations you may be in a strong case of doubt 1 min. before adhan, doubt is the opposite of uncertainty and leads to invalidity.